# Missing Mongoose Schema Property Still Being Returned

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given a schema that looks like this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
```

And the database contains "name" for all objects in the collection. But then I change it and *remove name*

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ size: 'string' });
```

And then I do a find on it:

```
schema.find({}).exec().then( (objs) => {
   // objs[0].name still exists
```

I thought that if the schema didn't specify a property then it wouldn't exist on the found objects. Is this not the case? Is the only way to remove a property, to actually remove it from the object in mongo?

Comment: Did the answer help you with your question? It helps others who use SO to indicate which answers helped/solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the original maintainer, [Aaron Heckmann](https://github.com/aheckmann):

> [M]ongoose "plays nice" with existing data in the db, not deleting it unless you tell it to.
>
> [D]eleting the property would work if mongoose was able to hook into that even but alas it cannot. [H]owever you can completely remove the property from your document by setting the values to `undefined` which will trigger an `$unset`.

Source: [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/eMwOJwUzK7w)

Basically Mongoose attempts to be non-destructive to existing data. If a property is no longer needed you could run an update on the database to unset the value which would remove the property from every document in the collection.